# Java VisualVM JMX connection in IBM Websphere

Tags: java, websphere, rmi, jmx, visualvm

I am trying to monitor IBM Websphere using JVisualVM but i cannot connect.
Error Says "Cannot connect to  using service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi:///jmxrmi"
This is the first time were using IBM JDK in WAS. this is working smoothly on our old Solaris Server.

**Specs and configuration.**

- IBM Websphere 8.0.0.5
- Red Hat Linux
- Java version = 1.6.0, Java Compiler = j9jit26, Java VM name = IBM J9
  VM
- JVM Args:

> -Djavax.management.builder.initial= -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=19823 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Xgcpolicy:gencon -verbose:gc -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=

**VISUALVM Error.**

```
[com.sun.tools.visualvm.jmx.impl.JmxModelImpl]: connect(service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://<MYHOST>:19823/jmxrmi)
java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:505)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:954)
Caused: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1343)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:728)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:123)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at java.io.DataOutputStream.flush(DataOutputStream.java:123)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:229)
Caused: java.rmi.ConnectIOException: error during JRMP connection establishment; nested exception is: 
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:304)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:342)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.lookup(RegistryContext.java:118)
Caused: javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectIOException: error during JRMP connection establishment; nested exception is: 
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake]
    at com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.lookup(RegistryContext.java:122)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.url.GenericURLContext.lookup(GenericURLContext.java:205)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.findRMIServerJNDI(RMIConnector.java:1929)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.findRMIServer(RMIConnector.java:1896)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect(RMIConnector.java:287)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect(RMIConnector.java:369)
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.jmx.impl.JmxModelImpl$ProxyClient.tryConnect(JmxModelImpl.java:512)
[catch] at com.sun.tools.visualvm.jmx.impl.JmxModelImpl$ProxyClient.connect(JmxModelImpl.java:449)
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.jmx.impl.JmxModelImpl.connect(JmxModelImpl.java:203)
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.jmx.impl.JmxModelImpl.<init>(JmxModelImpl.java:192)
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.jmx.impl.JmxModelProvider.createModelFor(JmxModelProvider.java:40)
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.jmx.impl.JmxModelProvider.createModelFor(JmxModelProvider.java:21)
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.core.model.ModelFactory.getModel(ModelFactory.java:91)
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.tools.jmx.JmxModelFactory.getJmxModelFor(JmxModelFactory.java:49)
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.jmx.impl.JmxApplicationProvider.addJmxApplication(JmxApplicationProvider.java:261)
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.jmx.impl.JmxApplicationProvider.createJmxApplication(JmxApplicationProvider.java:170)
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.jmx.JmxApplicationsSupport.createJmxApplicationImpl(JmxApplicationsSupport.java:273)
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.jmx.JmxApplicationsSupport.createJmxApplicationInteractive(JmxApplicationsSupport.java:250)
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.jmx.impl.AddJMXConnectionAction$1.run(AddJMXConnectionAction.java:60)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:1393)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:2005)
```

**Checkings ive done.**

1. expose the JMX port in the server. i can see that it is listening.
   and i can even connect into in using telnet  <19823> in my
   laptop.
2. Im not seeing any error log in websphere side.

Comment: Make sure that `-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=` have IP address of your Websphere server.

Comment: @TomasHurka yess, it's included. weird thing is that looks like ssl=false is not working since im getting SSL error. do you have idea if i need to attach some libs to make this work in IBM JDK? same config is used in hotspot JVM and got no error

Answer (score 0):

Got this issue resolved by trying to disable iptables in the linux.
then somehow, operations/support approved to open some default ephemeral ports for RMI to use.

Final JVM args is the below.

> -Djavax.management.builder.initial= -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=PORT -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=PORT -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=HOST

Thank you!